# array loop keep a certain number of keys and replace the keys with an associative key based on the elements

Tags: php

Hello i have the following array http://codepad.org/LLQ7CAm8 with the following code.

```
unset($val[0]);
unset($val[1]);
unset($val[2]);
$val = array_filter($val);
    foreach($val as $key => $val)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        //$val = array_splice($val, );
        print_r($val);
    }
}
```

what i would like to achieve is to keep first 65 keys from each array and delete the rest and if it's posible to change the keys with the elements from the second array example: 
$val['Titlu garantie'] = '144203T1';
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting the array elments you can use `array_splice()` in php

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input,3);
print_r($input);
```

Ouptput

```
Array
    (
        [0] => red
        [1] => green
        [2] => blue
    )
```

So you can do `array_splice($val,65);`

Comment: did like that but the split wasn't right..  that's why i asked here :d
my bad was setting a var on it.